# Is there any way to get live agent current chat session id?

Tags: liveagent

I am trying to obtain the agent current sessions id because I need to get the chat messages during the active session,  but I could not found in the Live Agent REST API documentation the way to get it. I was able to create session with the SessionId request but not it is what I need.
Any idea?
Thanks.